# partial class for business objects for joining tables in databases

Tags: c#, class, partial

is particial class a good solluction for something like this:

My two tables i the database look like this:

```
Table A int id*,  string Name
Table B int id*, string Ag

class A {
  public string Name;
}

class B {
  public string Ag;
}
```

Now i want to join booth tables A with B on id

```
public class JoinedTable
{
    partial class A : A
    {

    }
    partial class B : B
    {

    }
}
```

What do you think about this?
Cheers!

Comment: Have you tried it? Any compilation errors?

Comment: Your partial here isn't adding anything unless you have two different parts of a partial class. I'm not sure your understanding of `partial class` is quite right. Also, what does it *mean* for `A : A`? even if they are different types, what does it *mean* to you? what is that describing?

Comment: what is this supposed to do class A : A

Comment: Or to put it another way: what are you actually trying to ***do*** here? We can see the code, but without understanding your *intent*, we have no way of saying whether that is a sensible approach.

Comment: No errors, but it doesn't work ;(

Comment: I want to get a BO that joins both BO without writing a new class. I think I need something like multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dotnet does not support multible inheritance.

If i understood you correctly you do not whant to write a composite class that contain properties for the subclasses `A` and `B`

Your partial classes aproach as a simulation for multible inheritnance only works if the class names for `A` and `B` are the same.

```
    partial class JoinedTable {
      public string Name;
    }

    partial class JoinedTable {
      public string Ag;
    }
```

My answer is **no** to

> is particial class a good solluction

Update

A workaround for this could be a database-view that joins the tables and you let your codegenerater generate the code for the view